# python find closest value in list

Tags: python, python-2.7

My shapes.txt is like:

```
shape_id,shape_pt_lat,shape_pt_lon,shape_pt_sequence
100-1-0_D,41.0180673531548,29.085973004423135,0
100-1-0_D,41.018257549826984,29.085232584769567,1
100-1-0_D,41.018438672415755,29.084250285389476,2
100-1-0_D,41.018926081703704,29.082072721166206,3
100-1-0_D,41.019004044993366,29.081607048036684,4
100-1-0_D,41.018951184935545,29.08119023014186,5
...There are thousands of lines like this
```

I added to list "shapes.txt" with in this way.

```
with codecs.open('/home/fatih/Desktop/10mart/deneme/shapes.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf8') as veridosya3:
    reader3 = csv.reader(veridosya3, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row3 in reader3:
        shapestxt.append(row3)
```

I have some coordinat values(lat,lon).I need to find closest lat,lon values from shapes.txt and get its sequence values.
How can i do that ?

The question is very clear so already answered very well by Szabolcs.

Comment: Closest to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used geopy to calculate the distance between two points, so try it:

```
import csv
from geopy.distance import vincenty

with open('tmp.txt', 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    fixed_coord = (41.49008, -71.312796)
    fixed_id = '100-1-0_D1'
    shapes = [{'distance': vincenty(fixed_coord, (shape['shape_pt_lat'], shape['shape_pt_lon'])).miles, 'sequence': shape['shape_pt_sequence'],} for shape in reader if shape['shape_id'] == fixed_id]
    closest = min(shapes, key=lambda shape: shape['distance'])
print closest
```

This will output:

`{'distance': 4887.556987553742, 'sequence': '5'}`

To break it down:
I read in the file with `csv.DictReader` so it's easier to access each value by its title.

Then I create an arbitrary `fixed_coord`.

After I calculate the distance and the sequence of each coordinate in the `shapes` list.

Then I sort the `shapes` list by the `distance` key of each shape, and finally return the closest shape's distance and sequence values.

Comment: @FatihAltun Added comparision in shapes list comprehension. Take a look at it.

Comment: @FatihAltun consider replacing `sorted` when generating `closest` to `min` like in the edit I made.

Comment: i will ask that comparision but i've tried and i did it like you did :).Thank you so much for your successful answer

Comment: very good answer I must say. Not only it's correct (as opposed to mine :)) but it's very pythonic. Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

```
from geopy.distance import vincenty
import codecs, csv

def get_smallest_distance(reference_coordonate, coordonates):
    coordonates = [dict(coordonate, geodistance=vincenty((coordonate['lat'], coordonate['lng']), reference_coordonate).kilometers) for coordonate in coordonates]

    return min(coordonates, key=lambda k: k['geodistance'])

coordonates = []
shapestxt = []
path = '/home/dan/projects/python/tools/coordonates.txt'

with codecs.open(path, 'r+', encoding='utf8') as veridosya3:
    reader3 = csv.reader(veridosya3, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row3 in reader3:
        coordonates.append({'lat': float(row3[1]), 'lng': float(row3[2])})

reference_coordonate = (42.1, 28) # as an example
print get_smallest_distance(reference_coordonate, coordonates)
```